# How do you watch for changes using an NPM linked library and an Angular CLI app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

**I have the following setup:**

1. A local UI library I'm developing
2. An Angular application that is consuming that library
3. I am using NPM link so that I don't have to publish the library every time I want to test changes in the application that is consuming it.
4. The Angular application is being served via the Angular CLI (`ng serve --aot`)
5. I am watching the UI library for changes so that it automatically builds using `gulp watch`

**I have two problems:**

Whenever I make a change to the library, `gulp watch` will trigger a new build. However, this build fails with the following error:

`Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink`

I can solve this problem by triggering manual builds of the UI library, but there is another problem: the running application sees changes to the linked library, and triggers its own build as soon as the UI library build starts. This creates a race condition whereby the Angular CLI will not wait for the UI library to finish building.

What is the correct, standard way to watch for changes in a local NPM library, with an Angular CLI application, using NPM link?

Comment: If you are pulling the library in to your local project using NPM, but also building/iterating on it, could you just have your main project's `watch` ignore files in your `node_modules` folder and run a seperate `watch` for the library files you are working on?